# How to generate Curve 25519 key pair with ECDH in node js?

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography, ecdh, curve-25519

I want to generate a **Curve25519** key pair with **ECDH** for the encryption and decryption. I'm using the **Crypto** node module to generates a keypair.

But, I failed to generate a keypair with the ECDH algorithm.

**NodeJS**

```
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('x25519', {

publicKeyEncoding: {
   type: 'spki',
   format: 'pem'
},
privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem',
  }
});
```

Output:

```
{
    "publicKey": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMCowBQYDK2VuAyEAR+Bv9DCDFDYih5wHHLp5CALMyUv6AMpuO0lEQkvNMQ8=\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
    "privateKey": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VuBCIEIMiiTraPY1IO/4m0wV8y4LZgnFy70xR8c8s3nmmxTSFT\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
}
```

Here is one of the Java code using **bouncycastle**

https://github.com/gsasikumar/forwardsecrecy

Output of Java code:

```
{
  "privateKey": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "errorInfo": null,
  "KeyMaterials": {
    "cryptoAlg": "ECDH",
    "curve": "curve25519",
    "params": "",
    "DHPublicKey": {
      "expiry": "2020-10-15T11:29:20.848Z",
      "Parameter": "",
      "KeyValue": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBMTCB6gYHKoZIzj0CATCB3gIBATArBgcqhkjOPQEBAiB/////////////////////////////////////////7TBEBCAqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqYSRShRAQge0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0JgtenHcQyGQEQQQqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq0kWiCuGaG4oIa04B7dLHdI0UySPU1+bXxhsinpxaJ+ztPZAiAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFN753qL3nNZYEmMaXPXT7QIBCANCAARuesOo7QMm9k+qILijTeh7yz0HU9DJrPIAnqVudaaG6w0/1n1ySnxa+X0bjWpUvmJA0IIKHO8baWBYp9BC4nWM-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me for the same?

Comment: Should be possible as of 13.9. You should post your code and describe the problems.

Comment: @Topaco, I added the code.

Comment: It looks like it worked. Why do you say it failed?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The node js output key length is different than the Java output key. I need the same key length as java output.

Comment: They should be compatible keys for most applications. The node keys use a single OID to convey that this is curve25519, what you call the "Java output" uses a generic elliptic curve public key OID and then includes all the curve25519 parameters.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, Thanks for your response. So have you know any other way to do the same as bouncycastle functionality in node js.

Comment: @IshaPadalia, Can you help and post your node.js solution here, I am implementing the same and facing few difficulties in generating keys and converting them to base 64